# C++11: does returning objects by value never throw exceptions when a move ctor is defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, return, noexcept

In C++11 and later standards, is it guaranteed that the (possibly exception-throwing) copy ctor is *not* called when returning a class object by value from a function - provided a move ctor is defined for this class? Background: Suppose

```
struct X {
   X() {}
   X(const X&) {/* code that might throw exceptions */}
   X(X&&) {/* code that never throws exceptions */}
   ...
};
```

and

```
X my_func(some_type& t)
{
   X x;
   // code that modifies t and x but never throws exceptions
   return x;
}
```

Now, does, for instance, an expression such as

```
some_other_func(my_func(t));
```

never throw exceptions (i.e., is this guaranteed?) provided the function `some_other_func(const X&)` does not throw exceptions? And what if the signature of `some_other_func` were `some_other_func(X)`?

Comment: In your hypothetical situation, is the default constructor of `X` guaranteed to not throw?

Comment: @ChrisDrew It is above, and it is an empty constructor.

Comment: @Yakk, sure,  I was wondering if there was something missing because I am surprised that `X` can be constructed and filled without throwing but can't be copied without throwing.

Comment: @Yakk for example, perhaps `X` contains member variables not shown that have default  constructors that could throw.

Comment: @ChrisDrew `if (rand()==7) throw 7;` ;)

Comment: @Yakk, Perhaps, or more likely allocate memory dynamically that could throw a `bad_alloc` exception.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is simple: a function is treated as if it can throw exceptions unless it's marked as a function which cannot. A move constructor is a function like any other in this respect. When defined manually, it is considered potentially throwing unless defined `noexcept`.

Implicitly defaulted functions (i.e. the auto-provided copy & move operations) generally follow the logic of: declared as `noexcept` if and only if all functions which it calls are `noexcept`.

Comment: My question aims at *copy* ctor calls "during" the return process from a function, provided a move ctor is available. Of course, the move ctor in the above example could be declared noexcept, but this is not the point I intended to draw attention to.

Comment: @Teilhart In the *language* itself, choice of move ctor vs. copy ctor is never driven by exception specifications (or lack thereof). If a move operation is available, ti will be used when the RHS is an rvalue. Otherwise (no move op or LHS is lvalue), copy operation will be used. *Library* things like `std::vector` have more complicated rules, due to exception safety concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are never spontaneously generated in a well formed C++ program that only excecutes defined behavior.

If your code is a well formed program, you never call or interact with a language or library feature that is permitted to throw exceptions, and the code you write not throw exceptions (explicitly), then the result is code that won't throw exceptions.

Unless you mark your functions and methods as `noexcept`, the compiler and standard library may not realize this, and may assume your code throws exceptions (even though it cannot).  In some cases this could cause the compiler to allocate memory and throw an exception out of caution that your code could throw an exception, or call a different method (copy instead of move for example in certain vector operations).

What you *should* do is mark `X(X&&)` and `X()` as `noexcept`, and this particular problem goes away.

Despite this, your *exact code* won't throw, unless `some_other_function` doesn't take a `X` but instead a type created from an `X` and that operation could throw, or the body of `some_other_function` could throw.